# Writing Scheduler/RTOS in XC8

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, rtos, xc8

I have an interest in writing a scheduler/RTOS project in XC8 using an enhanced MCU with access to the hardware stack.

I am trying to figure out how to control the creation of the software stacks so each task's software stack will get a certain range in the general purpose ram.

Conceptually this is all easy to program in ASM but I want to be able to write C programs and have the software stacks for each task be put into the right address space.

There doesn't appear to be an option to create a separate software stack for a certain section of code or even create multiple software stacks - how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: With an 8-bit PIC, you are talking at most of about 8K ROM and not a lot of RAM.  How much space are you expecting for each stack

Comment: Sub 250 bytes. This will allow roughly 4 tasks to run. Also the device has linear ram access which can be used verse all the bank switching.

Answer (score 1):

Stack switching is the responsibility of teh scheduler,not teh compiler - so you will not find a *compiler option for that*.  You have to implement that in the scheduler you are intending to write - that is in fact most of what a scheduler does.

In an RTOS, switching context involves storing all the registers relating to one thread of execution and replacing them with those of another. This includes replacing the stack-pointer - that is how you switch stacks between threads. A context switch is completed when the program-counter register is loaded effecting a jump to the new thread's last execution point (with all its registers, including the stack-pointer restored.

The context switch itself necessarily involves at least a small amount of assembler code, but much of it may still be written in C, and tasks themselves may be written in C.. A good description of a simple RTOS scheduler is provided in Jean Labrosse's book on μC/OS-II - [freely available in PDF](https://www.micrium.com/books/ucosii/).  A PIC18 port of μC/OS-II is described [here](http://www.sputnickonline.com/projects/programs/micro/uCOS_for_PIC18/details.html) with download.

Comment: Thanks, yes I understand. I was having an issue with controlling where the software stack is located using XC8 and having it use appropriate variables(everything gets put on the separate stack verses using what it called a "compiled stack". In addition I was having an issue finding out what registers the compiler uses or if it's possible to direct them to be from a certain area of ram. In ASM this would all be pretty easy but I feel the XC8 users guide doesn't give enough detail on compiler implementation.

Comment: the book you refer to can be found here: https://www.micrium.com/books/ucosii/ (your link links to you own home folder!)

Comment: @JonathanV :  Thanks, fixed the link.